# Want to submit photos from an app without using default mail client (using Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm developing an app using AppShed.com with my students. AppShed allows for the use of Javascript.

With that said, we are creating a crowdsource conference app, specific to an educational technology conference. Our goal is to make it where users can submit their photos to our Flickr account through the app. If I am thinking through this right, we could set it up where users navigate to the Capture page, take a picture (or choose one) then it is sent via email to our flickr pool's email address.

I really want the user to simply have to click Submit and not have to use their mail client.

I am ok with everyone's emails coming from the same account (e.g. ourcoolapp@yahoo.com) and going to the same flickr email address (with subject and tags). I don't need to know who submitted them (users who want to submit photos themselves can do so and just tag on their own).

I can use any Javascript in the app, if that helps.

Any help for me and my students would be appreciated.

EDIT: I understand (thanks to the comment below) that this may require something server-side. I have web hosting I can use, but don't know where to begin. Any resources are appreciated.

Comment: You can't send email directly from Javascript. It either has to use the user's email client, or go through a server script that sends email.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I have a web server I could parse a script through to send the email. Can you direct me to some resources on this?

Comment: You don't need to do any parsing. Just have the web page submit a form or use AJAX to send the photo to the server script. Google "send mail using <language>", replacing <language> with the scripting language you'll use.

Comment: Thanks, Googling now. Sorry for the noob nature of the question, I'm a school teacher, not an IT pro. Just trying to help teach my kids.

Comment: While you probably can accomplish this with a server-side script sending the photo via an e-mail, I think the best practice here would be to post the photo directly to Flickr using their API: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

Comment: Thanks, will look into that. In my limited understanding, I thought using the Flickr API would force each user to OAuth with our app, and I thought that might be a little cumbersome from a UI perspective. I will look further into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to upload photos to flickr using JavaScript, you need to use their API.  here is how:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  action="http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/">  
<input type="file" name="photo"/>  
<input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="<INSERT_FLICKR_API_KEY_HERE>"/>  
<input type="hidden" name="auth_token" value="<INSERT_FLICKR_AUTH_TOKEN_HERE>"/>  
<input type="hidden" name="api_sig" value="<INSERT_FLICKR_API_SIG_HERE>"/>  
<input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Upload"/>  
</form>
```

Remember while generating the MD5 hash of the signature string you need to upload every element of the form excluding the photo field. This includes the submit buttons value since contents of the entire form are posted to the URL.

```
var hash = MD5(secret + "api_key" + apikey  + "auth_token" + token + "submitUpload");
```

now, you may notice that this a regular HTML form with POST method set to post at flickr's server, so you can override the `submit` event & submit the form via `XMLHttpRequest` aka ajax using JavaScript.

As you notice this is lot simpler than trying to upload via Email. Find more info here:

- [The Ultimate Guide to Decoding the Flickr API](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-ultimate-guide-to-decoding-the-flickr-api/)
- [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/)

Comment: This is absolutely outstanding. Thank you for the help! My students and I are in awe. :) Much appreciated.